# Redistribute MsBuild in our application

Tags: msbuild

Is it possible to redistribute msbuild in our application installer, so we can use msbuild to perform some maintenance tasks?

Comment: read the license/redistribution agreements/guidelines, ask microsoft, ask a lawyer. this is not the right place for legal issues.

Comment: @Mat: In general I'd agree but I believe a useful answer is possible so not joining in vtc

Comment: Let me clarify my question: I need "something" like msbuild that can be distributed with my application. I know ant is a good example, but distributing ant will requires JDK, and additional setup on client computer. I think if I can use msbuild from .NET framework, that will be great. Just a question, is it possible to do that? Is there any "silent" installer for msbuild that can deployed to client computers?

Comment: Yes, all .NET apps with real installers [need to do a silent install](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/04/04/10149346.aspx) of the kind you speak of. Are you trying to manage repeated execution of stacks of interdependent tasks, taking advantage of parallelism? While there's nothing wrong with msbuild, if you were to explain what you're doing that makes xml tags the best language for it it might helper people suggesting alternatives. Maintenance tasks sounds more like PowerShell and/or PowerGUI (but both of those cannnot be assumed to be installed either xcept on Win7+)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible to redistribute the framework. Although the maintenance tasks may be a job for an installer custom task not msbuild. You'd have to elaborate on your requirement.

You could put a check/condition in an installer, but your pretty much likely to have at least 2.0 framework on any machine. You could write a simple msbuild script that checked the version of the msbuild installed and then executed a framework redistributable.
i.e. Find what folders exist under $(windir)/Microsoft.NET/Framework

You can add these redist to most installers, wix, installshield etc so i dont see a problem.

Comment: [Careful on saying its always there](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/04/04/10149346.aspx). Also checking the install folder is not how you check - need to check markers in the registry. Bottom line that your advice that the installer can deploy .NET too is the main point.

Comment: I didnt say always. Product guid in registry etc .

Comment: You said 'pretty much likely' which is useful to bear in mind when assessing the likely installation time impact (i.e., in 97% of cases boostrapping .NET will be unnecessary vs the OP's question - can I redistribute it (which implies that the OP is worried about it being there in *all* cases*). For the same reason, I stand behind checking for folders being present as being very irresponsible loose talk - i.e., your i.e. is a completely wrong example despite the thrust of your point being correct.

Comment: I didnt -1 but the fact that you're still presenting the errors as irrelevant details when they are pretty critical makes me want to. Anyway, over and out, KTHXBYE...

Answer (score 1):

No, in general you dont for a variety of reasons, but it's part of a standard install of the Runtime CLR.

Note that the Client Profile subset does not include it so your installer needs to verify/install the non-CP version is present.

Please consider that the best tool for installation is an installer though (a point very well made in [the Continuous Delivery book](http://continuousdelivery.com)) - but it's definitely a continuum, with PowerShell and/or [psake](https://github.com/JamesKovacs/psake) in the mix too.